# POST method is not working when submitting form in django

Tags: python, django

I created feedback form using form module in django. i wrote the code for printing form data entered by user when submitting form. But when i submit the form post is not working as a result user data is not printing . I am beginner in django .I tried lots to solve this .but i couldn't. please help me if anyone know what is my wrong in code

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms 
class feedbackForm(forms.Form):
    Name=forms.CharField()
    RollNo=forms.IntegerField()
    Email=forms.EmailField()
    feedback=forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .import forms
def feedback_view(request):
    form=forms.feedbackForm()
    if request.method=='POST':
       form=forms.feedbackForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
            print('form validation success and  printing feeback info')
            print('student name :',form.cleaned_data['Name'])
            print('student RollNo:',form.cleaned_data['RollNo'])
            print('student Email :',form.cleaned_data['Email'])
            print('student feedback :',form.cleaned_data['feedback'])
    return render(request,'testapp/feedback.html',{'form':form})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from testapp import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^feed/', views.feedback_view),
]
```

**feedback.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static "css/demo1001.css"%}">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container"  align=center>
       <h1>ShefJaz Student 2feedbackform </h1><br>

       <form   method="post">
        {{form.as_p}}
        {%csrf_token%}
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">sumbit feedback</button>

      </form>


    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First a all, python class always must be in capital letter class FeedbackForm(forms.ModelForm):

Comment: button's type must be "submit": `<button type="submit">Submit feedback</button>`

Answer (score 0):

You are using a function as a API view so, It should be mentioned in the method decorator like shown below

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
 @api_view(['POST'])
 def feedback_view(request):
      .....
    your code
      .....
```

Hope it will give you the solution.

more than one HTTP methods can be used like shown here.

```
@api_view(['POST', 'GET'])
```